# Testing observables in angular

Tags: angular, jestjs

I'm trying to test an observable service in angular with jest. Here is the code of the service:

```
  getGenealogyTree(genealogyCode: string): Observable<GenealogyTree> {
const queryParams = new HttpParams().set('genealogyCode', genealogyCode);
const url = `${environment.janetUrl}/genealogy/genealogyCode`;
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/json');
return this.httpClient.get<GenealogyTree>(url, { headers, params: queryParams });
```

}

And here is the declaration of the spec (mock and all those stuff):

```
let janetService: any;
    janetService = {
  getGenealogyTree: jest.fn(() => {
    return scheduled([{
      product: {},
      children: [],
      parents: [],
      deviceTypes: []
    }], asyncScheduler);
  }),
  getGenealogyTreeFiltered: jest.fn(() => {
    return scheduled([{
      product: {},
      children: [],
      parents: [],
      deviceTypes: []
    }], asyncScheduler);
  }),
};
```

But when I run the test that uses the service, the console shows me the next error:

**TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.**

Here is the result:

```
      79 |       .getGenealogyTree(genealogyCode)
  80 |       .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
> 81 |       .subscribe((result) => {
     |        ^
  82 |         this.genealogyTree = result;
  83 |       });
  84 |   }
```

Any idea why happens this ??

Comment: You can use `of` from RxJs to create a stub for an observable.

Comment: @JulienD it doesn't works

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: this usually means that `janetService` isn't provided in the TestBed, because its code looks right and the only issue is that `.getGenealogyTree(genealogyCode)` doesn't call the mock.